# jquery if mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a img with a hover function to reveal an element. Some of this new element overlaps the img so if I then hover over the new element, because the cursor is no longer over the img, the element hides itself and then instantly reappears because the cursor is over the img again. I need to somehow ignore the mouseout command if the cursor is over the img which is within the new element (the only part of the new element which is overlapping the main image).

It's a tricky one to explain but here's the code:

jquery (with bit i'm not sure how to do)

```
$("div > img").hover( function() {

        $(this).parent().find("span").slideDown(100);

    }, function() {

        if (user is hovering over the span) {
                    // do nothing
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find("span").slideUp(100);
        }
    });
```

html

```
<div>
    <img src="/images/icons/dm.jpg" width="54" height="54" />
    <span><strong>Test</strong><br />test2<img src="/images/arrow.png" width="19" height="17" /></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much easier approach would be just having the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) on that parent `<div>` like this:

```
$("div").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("span").slideDown(100);
}, function() {
    $(this).find("span").slideUp(100);
});
```

Since you effectively only want to affect the `<span>` when hovering over the `<div>` (in which only the `<img>` is initially visible)...it makes more sense to stick your handler there, you see how much simpler the code gets :)  I'd just give that `<div>` some class you can use in a selector (to make it more specific) and you're all set.

Comment: See what you're saying there, but it doesn't quite work in this case. The element that appears is larger than the containing div. I want the new element to slide away if I hover out of the div, but your way means I also have to hover out of the space taken up by the new element. Does that make sense???

Comment: @Tom - But that's what you were asking...to do nothing if you are still hovered over the `<span>`, was it not?

Comment: Another good point, I'll try to explain myself properly!! - The img within the span overlaps with main image (with the hover function). The rest of the span is outside of this area. So I actually only need it to ignore the hover out if the cursor is over the img within the span.

Comment: OK. So having looked at this properly I can see you're right! This is certainly the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt at what you describe

http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/cQxVv/

but @Nicks solution is way more elegant.