# How to make layer visible on mouseover using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip, mouseover

If you move your mouse on any **tag** in StackOverflow, you see a black tool tip. Can somebody help me how can I make that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery if mouseover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409022/jquery-if-mouseover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your real needs but you could use the TipTip plugin and its KeepAlive option:
http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

Answer (score -1):

> > [jquery if mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409022/jquery-if-mouseover)